# How to sort a number field by number in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose, and the field is defined like this:

```
score: {type: Number, default: 0},
```

They seem to be stored as numbers in the results.

But when I sort using this field (with other fields)

```
sort: {specified: -1, featured: -1, score: -1, likes: -1, yearCreated: -1 ,createdAt: -1}
```

It sorts them alphabetically, ie gives me all the numbers that start with 9, then 8, then 7. I want it to put the bigger numbers first. I've essentially the same thing on another field and didn't have this problem.

paste of several results: https://pastebin.com/bRtAAhnn

The field is "score".

Comment: Can you paste in an example of your data, direct from the db? It might show whether there's a problem with the way the data has been stored.

Comment: I will get that, but i did check and they seemed to be stored as numbers (not quoted)

Comment: Also, it would be clearer if you could include an example of the query results you expected, compared to the query results you actually got.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I figured it out. Turns out another field I was sorting by which was supposed to be true or false also had some undefined values, which were being grouped together.